# Integration of $|\text{cos}(t)|$

Tags: integration, limits

The integration is $\int_{0}^{\infty}|\text{cos}(t)|dt$. I have been trying to show that this evaluates to infinity by expressing the $|\text{cos}(t)|$ in terms of the square root of its square, but I wasn't getting anywhere. In the end, I was able to prove it by dividing it into an infinite sum of its positive and (inverted) negative intervals as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}|\text{cos}(t)|dt=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\text{cos}(t)dt-\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\text{cos}(t)dt+\int_{3\pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\text{cos}(t)dt-\int_{5\pi/2}^{7\pi/2}\text{cos}(t)dt+\ldots$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}(2n+1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\text{cos}(t)dt=\lim_{n \to \infty}(2n+1)\rightarrow\infty$$

Is this proof valid? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: i belive its valid - $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos(x)dx} \to \infty$

Comment: The definition of $\int_0^\infty$ is $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_0^x$. It's not too difficult to apply this and see that you're taking the limit of something that increases monotonically and without bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\int_{0}^{2 \pi}|\text{cos}(t)|dt=4$. Since $\cos$ is $2 \pi$ - periodic, we get

$\int_{0}^{2 n \pi}|\text{cos}(t)|dt=4n$  for all natoral $n$. Hence

$\int_{0}^{2 n \pi}|\text{cos}(t)|dt \to \infty$  for $n \to \infty$.

Conclusion: $\int_{0}^{\infty}|\text{cos}(t)|dt$ is divergent.